# where are my log files in heroku?

Tags: logging, heroku

I have logging configured going to console and a log file. In heroku world, does it even make sense to log to a file? Is there any way I can retrive the log file?

Answer (score 15):

[Logs are streams, not files.](http://adam.heroku.com/past/2011/4/1/logs_are_streams_not_files/)

To access the logging stream, you simply `heroku logs` and you'll see the full stream.  Anything you output with your applications logger will go here.

You do not have log files.

Should you wish to capture files to frame and put on your wall, sign up for a service such as [Papertrail](http://papertrailapp.com) and use the syslog drains to get your Heroku logs into there.  From there they can dump to S3.

Answer (score 8):

To get the logs, just type in `heroku logs` or `heroku logs -n X` in your shell.

Where `X` can be any number up to `1500`, denoting the number of lines you want to fetch. If you want to archive your log, you need to use a syslog drain, as is outlined [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging).

Comment: a good answer but not what I asked. I know how to get logs by doing `heroku logs'. What I asked is log files not stdout logs.

Comment: I (more specifically) address your question in the second part of my answer. To get a log "file" (or archive), you need to use the syslog drain. Heroku doesn't save log files.

Comment: Drains are free.  heroku drains:add <your_syslog_url>

Answer (score 3):

Use this shell command to save your logs locally using heroku cli:

```
heroku logs -n number_of_lines --app application_name >> file_name.txt
```

`>>` will append the command output to the file and saves it: `file_name.txt`

`number_of_lines` is limited to a maximum of 1500 by heroku.

Sample command:

```
heroku logs -n 500 --app sample_app >> logs.txt
```

Thanks to the [Anuja Joshi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29911308/5663219)