# How to save Heroku logs to text file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, heroku

I am having a problem with logs in Heroku. When I want to look at the logs, sometimes I have missed a few lines. How can I save Heroku server logs to file.txt, or any other file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try this:

`heroku logs -n number_of_lines --app application_name >> file_name`

`>>` operator will appends the command output to the end of a file : `file_name`

however, heroku keeps the last 1,500 lines of consolidated logs. If you’d like to persist more than 1,500 lines for long-term storage, search, alerting, filtering and other processing, you can use [logging Add-on Providers](https://addons.heroku.com/#logging).

Answer (score 1):

Heroku has several logging add-ons (most have zero-cost tiers).  Easy to set up.
Check out [Logging Add-Ons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons#logging)